# TypeScript classes are merged internally

Tags: javascript, typescript

Not sure if this is a pure `TypeScript` issue or also depening on how it gets compiled into `javascript`.

I have two classed defined in the same module (different files)

```
module Modules.Home.Overview {

    export class Tours {
        private localStorageKey : string = "Home.Tours";

        private $tourBootgrid: JQuery;
    }
}
```

and

```
module Modules.Home.Overview {

    export class Events {
        private localStorageKey : string = "Home.Events";

        private $eventBootgrid: JQuery;
    }
}
```

I use instances of both classes in the same View. When looking at the dev.tools in chrome, it show me for `_this`

```
_this.localStorageKey = "Home.Tours" or "Home.Events"
_this.$tourBootgrid = Object
_this.$eventBootgrid = Object
```

which seems to me like the `classes` have been merged into one.

What am I doing wrong here? I thought the two `instances` are on their own.

**Update #1**

In both classes I bind to the click-event of an `bootstrap` dropdown, like

```
bindTourTypeChange = (): void => {
    this.$tourTypeDropDown.find("li a").on(Events.click, (evt:Event) => {
        this.setTourType($(evt.target).data("tourtype"));
        this.$tourBootgrid.bootgrid("reload");
    });
};
```

and

```
bindEventTypeChange = (): void => {
    this.$eventTypeDropDown.find("li a").on(Events.click, (evt:Event) => {
        this.setEventType($(evt.target).data("eventtype"));
        this.$eventBootgrid.bootgrid("reload");
    });
};
```

When setting a breakpoint inside the `click`-callback I can have a look at the `_this`-element under `Scope -> Closure` in dev.tools.

**Update #2**

The `TypeScript` gets compiled to `Tours.js`

```
var Modules;
(function (Modules) {
    (function (Home) {
        (function (Overview) {
            var Tours = (function () {
                function Tours(setup) {
                    var _this = this;

                    this.localStorageKey = "Home.Tours";
                }

                return Tours;
            })();
            Overview.Tours = Tours;
        })(Home.Overview || (Home.Overview = {}));
        var Overview = Home.Overview;
    })(Modules.Home || (Modules.Home = {}));
    var Home = Modules.Home;
})(Modules || (Modules = {}));
```

and to `Events.js`

```
var Modules;
(function (Modules) {
    (function (Home) {
        (function (Overview) {
            var Events = (function () {
                function Events(setup) {
                    var _this = this;

                    this.localStorageKey = "Home.Events";
                }

                return Events;
            })();
            Overview.Events = Events;
        })(Home.Overview || (Home.Overview = {}));
        var Overview = Home.Overview;
    })(Modules.Home || (Modules.Home = {}));
    var Home = Modules.Home;
})(Modules || (Modules = {}));
```

**Update #3**

Seems like I've found the issue.

I "initialized" the module by calling

```
Modules.Home.Overview.Tours(tourSetup)
```

and

```
Modules.Home.Overview.Events(eventSetup)
```

Changing this to

```
new Modules.Home.Overview.Tours(tourSetup)
```

and

```
new Modules.Home.Overview.Events(eventSetup)
```

seems to work. It now tells me

> Constructor call is not used or possibly used for side-effects.

Passing it to a variable is also not needed as I don't need the variable.

Could anybody please explain this behavior to me?

Comment: They'll be different classes. Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by what you see in the dev tools? How are you getting it to that state that it shows that? Maybe elsewhere there's an assignment being done to the `$tourBootgrid` and `$eventBootgrid` property on the same object?

Comment: @DavidSherret: Seems like I've found a - at least workaround - solution. Could you maybe explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain the behaviour you were having before you resolved it, if you use a class like this...

```
Modules.Home.Overview.Tours(tourSetup)
```

...the value of `this` inside the function created for the class will refer to the global object—`window`—and all the properties will be assigned to that.

You can do this test in JavaScript to see:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.test = "my string";
}

var myInstance;
myInstance = new MyClass(); // window.test == undefined, myInstance.test == "my string"
myInstance = MyClass();     // window.test == "my string", myInstance == undefined
```

On a sidenote, using a class in such a manner as `Modules.Home.Overview.Tours(tourSetup)` should be a compile error in TypeScript. I'm guessing you referenced it somewhere outside the reach of TypeScript's compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped me clarifying some things out. And, yes. You're right. I used this inside a `razor` View which does not has the `TypeScript`-compiler support, so the "error" was not highlighted.